# How can i make my footer responsive and text on it horizontally align?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and i can't seem to find a way that works to center and make my footer responsive.
This is my html code.

```css
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    border-top: 4px solid #F2D380 !important;
}
.socialIcon {//update
width: 20px;
}
```

````html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="col-lg-2 link_list">
    <a href="#"> Company  Information </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 link_list">
    <a href="#" > Privacy Policy and User Agreement </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 link_list">
    <a href="about.html"> About </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 link_list">
    <a href="#" >
      ©2019 Copyright claim
    </a>
  </div>

```
<div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3">//update
    <a href="#">
    <img src="images/linkedin.png" class=" socialIcon">
    </a>
 <a href="#" >
    <img src="images/instagram.png" class=" socialIcon">
    </a>
 <a href="#">
    <img src="images/facebook.png" class=" socialIcon">
    </a>
 <a href="#" >
    <img src="images/youtube.png" class="socialIcon">
 </a>
   </div>
</div>
```
````

I tried some bootstrap classes like justify-content-center but it simply does not work. I know i need to be looking at flexbox but it won't work and i don't know what the problem is.
Thank you in advance for answering.
*Update after i did what i saw in the comments it doesn't work with the socialmedia icons.

Comment: Can you a working fiddle here please so that I can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your codes. I explained what I changed in the comment lines. I removed the display table. You don't need this with this codes.

**Html :**

```
 <div id="footer">
        <div class="row text-center"> // I added row here, and I've got all the columns in a row, because all columns must be in a row. I added a "text center" class to keep all the text in the middle.
            <div class="col-sm-6 pb-sm-2  col-lg-3"> // that's how I arranged your columns . So they will adjust their width for each width value
                <a href="#"> Company Information </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <a href="#"> Privacy Policy and User Agreement </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 pb-sm-2  col-lg-3"> // "pb-sm-2" class to add padding bottom when dimensions are sm
                <a href="about.html"> About </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3">
                <a href="#">
                    ©2019 Copyright claim
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Css:**

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 2.5rem; */ you can use padding this way instead of specifying height. if you give a single height value, you will need to set height separately for all dimensions.
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border-top: 4px solid #F2D380 !important;
}
```

**I hope I could help. Good Luck!**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked! If i want to add social media icons i can just do that like you did above right?

Comment: Your welcome. You're using boltstrap. you can do it if you specify where and how much space the icons will take up as a colon system.

Comment: Yeah i did it, thank you. Now i got a scroll bar beneath my firefox because there is extra space added to the right of my page lol

Comment: you're obviously just learning the colon system. bootstrap documentation page, I recommend more detailed search of the grid system. you can also open a new post for your new problem, but first try to solve it yourself, this will be more useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

See the code below. You can forget about wrapping each anchor within a "div". It will be a lot easier to simply group them into the parent DIV and then target them. This should work and you can have more flexibility. Also, don't have to worry about flexbox or any external libraries.

```
<style>
body{
  height:2000px; /* for demonstration purposes*/
}

/* position the footer div RELATIVE and give it a "top" property of 100% so it always sits at the bottom regardless of your window height*/
#footer {
  position: relative;
  top:100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-top: 4px solid #F2D380 !important;
}
 /* center all items INSIDE the link_list DIV*/
.link_list{
  text-align:center;
}
/* target all the ANCHOR tags as inline elements*/
.link_list a {
    margin:50% 20px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="col-lg-2 link_list">
    <a href="#"> Company  Information </a>
    <a href="#" > Privacy Policy and User Agreement </a>
    <a href="about.html"> About </a>
    <a href="#" >©2019 Copyright claim</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:flex;` to `#footer` and it gets a bit of responsiveness.

quick fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/0b9hoag1/